# Using AES Encryption in an Application

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

This is the first time that I have worked with AES encryption, and I am somewhat confused. I am encrypting some sensitive data (no passwords just names, address, id number etc). I found a nice example of how to implement AES into my application. I understand that I supply the Password, Salt, Hash Algorithm, and Password Iterations to make the Key. This then creates the cipher text. Couple of questions I have is why is the KeySize dived by 8? If I wanted someone else to decrypt this what do I need to give them? Should the password, salt and IV be different every time I encrypt something new, if that is the case how to I ensure that the other person I want to use this information is always aware of that?

```
    public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string Password, string Salt, string HashAlgorithm, int PasswordIterations, string InitialVector, int KeySize)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
            byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
            byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
            byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();
            MemStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            MemStream.Dispose();
            cryptoStream.Dispose();
            Encryptor.Dispose();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I find [this extensive blog post and accompanying code](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/symmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp.aspx) very educational. Talks about background and how it's done in C#, and provides a nice useful utility class - highly recommended

Comment: @marc_s Not too fond of that one. It doesn't use a random IV, so you need a unique salt for each encryption, but article doesn't mention that requirement. Lack of MAC allows padding oracle attacks. Reading more than 20 bytes from PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 halves the performance for the defender without affecting the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
```

The keysize is divided by 8 because it's typically specified as a number of bits, but is being stored in a byte array.

The values that you keep the same are subject to the design of your program.  In practice, the IV should change every time, but should you choose, you could keep the key and salt constant.

I know that the IV is included in the output of the stream, so you don't have to include it explicitly for decryption (it will be read from the stream).  You shouldn't have to include the salt either for a similar reason.  I believe that the only value you'd need to decrypt the cyphertext is the key.  I may not be correct about this.  You can always write a decryptor and see what you need to pass to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`KeySize` is in bits. And as we know on any normal machine `1 byte = 8 bits`, hence division.

And what you need to give someone to be able to decrypt the data? `Key` and `IV` (Initialization Vector) will be enough.
That said - how do you usually do this? You send the `AES` encrypted data along with `Key` and `IV` encrypted using some asymetric encryption algorithm. This gives you higher level of protection - only someone with private key will be able to read `Key` and `IV` and use them do decrypt the most interesting data. You use generated `Key` and `IV` of some significant length to make yourself safe.

Why to do this this way? Because asymetric encryption is slow (very slow and for a good reason - to be harder to break), but symetric encryption (like AES) gives you high security if used with long key and is at the same time pretty fast. Combining both you get performance and security at high level.

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks. Follow up question so that would be combining something like RSA with AES to transfer it to the other party. Does the password/salt/IV need to be changed everything single time then?

Comment: Technically no - but it cost you nothing to do so! Every time you send the `Key` and `IV` anyway. Using `RijndaelManaged` to perform encryption you get both those values for free. With this - you don't even need need salt. All your passwords will be auto-generated so users will not need to think of them. Of course this also make sense only in some situations - like communication between applications that have private/public keys. Between single users - it would require user to have his priv/pub key. Still - I like this approach very muhc